# About ruby's free floating methods

Tags: ruby, methods

In ruby, free floating methods are attached to `Object`, does that mean all Classes have those methods since they all inherit from `Object`?

Or do they have some kind of exemption?

EDIT:
for clarification, I mean methods as defined by the coder like:

```
def some_method
   code...
end
```

Comment: Your question has already been answered here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/150824/is-the-puts-function-of-ruby-a-method-of-an-object

Comment: I did see that question but I'm not asking about  kernel methods like`puts` but rather methods as defined by the coder, I have added that clarification to the OP.

Comment: BTW: it would have taken you about 2 seconds to test this.

Comment: Why does every one think that just trying it will tell you everything you need to know about it? Your 100% right, I could have tried this but what if I missed something? Something I don't know but some else does or is common sense but missed simply becuase I didn't know to test a particular aspect. Also judging by the up votes, it's a potentially interesting question and will now be available as knowledge for others as well which I think can only be a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top level context is called *main*. It is an instance of the *Object* class. A method defined in this top level context will indeed be public to all objects, because they all inherit from the *Object* class.